# Updating the Apple Multiport USB-C Adapter (HDMI Dongle) on High Sierra

Tags: software-update, firmware

Here's the problem: High Sierra (as of 10.13) ships without the firmware update for this A/V dongle. This update package normally rests at "/System/Library/CoreServices/Firmware Updates", but this folder is empty following the update. So if you're stuck at an older Firmware Version (pre 2.33, article: Apple Support Article HT205858) there is no separate download for it, and you are on your own until Apple releases a hotfix.

Comment: Please don't answer the question within the question itself.  Create an answer so it can be upvoted and "selected" as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your way around a terminal follow this guide to get it solved. First off, make three checks; first that you are on Mac OS X High Sierra (Build 10.13 or greater), that your Multiport Adapter reports a firmware version below 2.33 (around 1.53 is old), and finally that the folder "/System/Library/CoreServices/Firmware Updates" is empty.

At a high-level, I guessed that I would find the firmware update package in an old Mac OS Combo Update file. Hunch turned out to be right, and I was able to install the firmware update. Lets trace those steps so you can do the same.

First up, kick off the download (around 1.5gb) of the macOS Sierra 10.12.6 Combo Update: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1931

At the same time, ensure Homebrew & XCode utils are installed on your system from brew.sh

Install pbzx, for extraction of update pkg Payloads.

```
brew install xz && brew link xz
git clone https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/pbzx.git
cd pbzx
clang -llzma -lxar -I /usr/local/include pbzx.c -o pbzx
#Install pbzx to path
mv pbzx /usr/local/bin/
```

Once the download has completed, mount & extract the update dmg.

```
open macosupdcombo10.12.6.dmg 
#Expand pkg contents to tmp folder.
pkgutil --expand /Volumes/macOS\ Sierra\ Update/macOSUpdCombo10.12.6.pkg /tmp/sierra/
cd /tmp/sierra 
#Extract payload contents to current directory
pbzx -n macOSUpdCombo10.12.6.pkg/Payload| cpio -i
```

Move the firmware update package from the extracted files to a local path, we'll use the user's home directory.

```
mv System/Library/CoreServices/Firmware\ Updates/USB-C\ Multiport\ Adapter/adapterupdate1.pkg ~/
```

Finally, execute the installer and reboot. Before you execute the installer - ensure that the Multiport adapter is plugged in, with nothing else plugged into it. Ensure that you have power connected to one USB-C port, and the Multiport adapter to the other. Apple's article recommends doing USB-C power-pass through, this did not work for me. You can try different configurations if this doesn't work.

```
#Kick off the install
sudo installer -pkg ~/adapterupdate1.pkg -target /
#Then reboot
sudo reboot
```

If all went well, System Information should report your USB-C Multiport Adapter is at firmware version 2.33.

Comment: The above process for installing the firmware update on High Sierra did not work for me. I was able to extract the updater package, but installer reports "This software is not supported on your system".